# PySide + QtSql - cannot load database drivers

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, odbc, pyside

Edit: I had to change the question because I found that the problem related not only to ODBC driver bu to all drivers such as MYSQL, SQLITE etc.

So the problem is this: I try to connect to a database using PySide and QtSql module.

The critical snippet:

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtSql
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')  
    # or others: QMYSQL, QSQLITE etc.
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and when I try to run it, I get a message:

```
QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers:
```

When I try equivalent `PyQt4` instead of `PySide`, I get no message which I assume means that the ODBC driver is available with PyQt4. However, unfortunately, I cannot switch my application from PySide to PyQt4 for many other reasons.

When I look into Python Lib folder I can see that `python-3.3.2\Lib\site-packages\PySide\plugins\sqldrivers` contains DLLs including `qsqlodbc4.dll`. So there is something more missing and I do not know what.

As I wrote the problem is not just with ODBC but with all database drivers.

Comment: what is the version of PySide ? For PySide older than 1.2.0 you need to call the PySide post-install script after installing, to generate the qt.conf file. For example: c:\Python33\Scripts\python.exe c:\Python33\Scripts\pyside_postinstall.py -install

Comment: It is version 1.2.1. It was bundled and installed with WinPython 3.3.2.3. When I look at intsllation log, it tells me that the post-install script was run. Even after I run it manullay myself, the problem with ODBC still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution here on stackoverflow here (relates to PyQt rather than PySide but it works): [PyQT can't find any SQL drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002842/pyqt-cant-find-any-sql-drivers)

In short - put this code before calling addDatabase:

```
site_pack_path = site.getsitepackages()[1]
QtGui.QApplication.addLibraryPath('{0}\\PySide\\plugins'.format(site_pack_path))
```

Comment: this is what the post-install script should do. Maybe there is some bug in post-install script. Could you run the script and send me here the output ? thanks

Comment: @V.K Any word on why this fix is even needed? It seems like a bug. Has it been reported to PySide, do you know?

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a similar issue using modern PySide6, here is the full answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72169911/211369

One of solutions is to define the `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variable, so that it contains the "sqldrivers" sub-directory with SQL plugins for Qt platform.

In your example, `QT_PLUGIN_PATH=c:/python-3.3.2/Lib/site-packages/PySide/plugins`

BTW almost a half of info known to me is is officially published at https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/deployment-plugins.html